# How export styles folder when create my library

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a custom react library. I'm using typescript, redux, and create-react-library to create it.

It' all ok, I can import my library from other projects, but my problem is that when I do `npm run build`. This generates a dist folder but doesn't add styles folder with scss and other files from fontello.

I have to create and script that when the post-build copy styles folder into the dist folder.

Also, in index.d.ts file of my library I have this import: `import "./styles/main.scss";` but doesn't import it. (Maybe I have to add something in tsconfig.json)

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./styles/main.scss";
import React from "react";
import MainTree from "./components/main";
import HierarchyTreeReducerState from "./redux/reducers/HierarchyTreeReducer";
import TreeReducerState from "./redux/reducers/TreeReducer";

interface Props {
    portal: boolean;
    removeBranchWithChildren: boolean;
    data?: any;
}

function TreeLibrary({ portal, removeBranchWithChildren, data }: Props) {
    return (
        <MainTree
            removeBranchWithChildren={removeBranchWithChildren}
            data={data}
            portal={portal}
        />
    );
}

export { TreeLibrary, HierarchyTreeReducerState, TreeReducerState };
```

The only solution I have found is to import the main.scss from the project that imports the library, like this:
`import "react-tree-library/dist/styles/main.scss";`

App.tsx from a project that imports my library:

```
import React from "react";

import { TreeLibrary } from "react-tree-library";
import "react-tree-library/dist/styles/main.scss";

import { completeData } from "./mockedData/huge";

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <TreeLibrary
                portal={false}
                data={completeData}
                removeBranchWithChildren={false}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

But I would like that when import my library I don't need to import styles manually.

How can I solve this?